# Condition in Sequence Diagram

Tags: conditional-statements, uml, sequence-diagram

How to represent condition statement in sequence diagram?

```
if(action == "Email"){
    sendMail();
}else{
    sentTextMesaage();
}
```

Which is good option in UML Gaurd, Option or Alternatives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In that case you would use an `alt` fragment:

[image]

The guard appears inside the segments of the fragment.